# Perl CGI form output

Tags: perl, cgi

Hi all I'm trying to write a form displaying a list of file with their size and timestamp and have user select one or more file to download them. 
I used hash to include filename size and timestamp related to each file the form look like this:

```
print $q->start_form(
        -name    => 'main_form',
        -method  => 'GET',
        -enctype => &CGI::URL_ENCODED,
        -onsubmit => '',
        -action => 'download_form.cgi', # Defaults to the current program
   );
    print $q->checkbox_group(
        -name     => 'file',
        -values   => \@files,
        -defaults => [''],
        -labels     => \%labels,
        -columns  => 1,
        -rows     => 1500,
    );   

    print $q->submit(
        -name     => 'submit_form',
        -value    => 'Download',
        -onsubmit => '',
    );
print $q->end_form;
```

Where
@files contain a list of the file I may want to download
and
%labels the name of file the size and the timestamp

this works fine I get a valid output but is not very nice to read, see an example below:

---

filename1.zip Size: 61.33MB [62799] Timestamp: 2017-02-22T07:13:00

filename2.txt Size: 62.52MB [64020] Timestamp: 2017-02-22T07:13:00

filename000003.log Size: 73.27MB [75033] Timestamp: 2017-02-22T06:00:00

file4.tar Size: 63.46MB [64982] Timestamp: 2017-02-22T05:59:00

---

It's all very compact and not optimal for the user, is there a way to have this displayed either in a table with 1 column for filename and the checkbox one for file size and one for the time stamp, or even display the 3 info in different color/font, i have available eventually 1 array @size with the size of each file and another @time with timestamp of each file, obviously @size[1] correspond to @files[1] and so on

Comment: Just create a table, and insert one checkox to each row in a loop while generating the table.

Comment: I'm not expert with perl so probably I'm missing something obvious but How do i put the table within the form / checkbox to read the user choice?

Comment: You don't have a Perl problem. You are using the outdated HTML generation stuff from CGI.pm, which has been deprecated and moved away into its own package. CGI.pm itself has been removed from the core and its author suggests that it is past its prime. Anyway, don't use the HTML generation stuff. Either use a proper template engine, or if that is not an option, just write the HTML yourself and `print` that. It's easier to read and less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a table, and insert one checkox to each row in a loop while generating the table.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use CGI;

my %labels = ( file1 => { size      => '61.33MB',
                          bytes     => 62799,
                          timestamp => '2017-02-22T07:13:00',
                        },
               file2 => { size      => '62.52MB',
                          bytes     => 64020,
                          timestamp => '2017-02-22T07:13:00',
                        });


my $q = 'CGI'->new;
print $q->header;
print $q->start_html;

print $q->start_form;
print $q->table({-border => 1},
    map {
        my $filename = $_;
        $q->Tr,
        $q->td(
            $q->checkbox('files', 0, $filename, $filename)
        ),
        map $q->td($labels{$filename}{$_}), qw( size bytes timestamp )
    } sort keys %labels
);

print $q->submit;

print $q->end_form;
```